Jenkins checkout scmGit kills ssh agent
I have a Jenkins pipeline that runs on say server "A". It Pulls code from Server "B" tests it and if the tests are succssful deploys it on server "C" which is a demo server on AWS. The relevant portion of the pipeline snippet is
stage("Deploy") {
    when {
        expression {
            currentBuild.result == null || currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS'
        }
     }
     steps{
         echo 'DEPLOYING application.........'
         sshagent(['MS-EC2-API-DEMO']) {
             dir('/home/ubuntu/public_html/mydomain.com/public') {
             echo 'CODE checkout from Source Code Repository in .........'
             sh 'pwd'
             checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'MS-EC2-API-DEMO-GIT', url: 'ssh://ubuntu@999.99.99.99:9999/home/mydirectory/gitrepos/ms.git']])
             echo 'Setting up DATABASE.........'
             sh 'php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force'
             sh 'php bin/console doctrine:database:create'
             sh 'php bin/console doctrine:schema:create'
             sh 'php bin/console ms:config-generator'
             sh 'php bin/phpunit'
            }
        }
    }
}

When the pipeline job runs it fails at the checkout stage with the following error
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ScBDZE6Xu8HU/agent.3604683
SSH_AGENT_PID=3604685
Running ssh-add (command line suppressed)
Identity added: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DS-MS@tmp/private_key_11064559423154765164.key (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DS-MS@tmp/private_key_11064559423154765164.key)
[ssh-agent] Started.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /home/ubuntu/public_html/mydomain/public
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
CODE checkout from Source Code Repository in .........
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 3604685 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
[Pipeline] // sshagent
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage    

For some reason the ssh agent seems to be failing at the Checkout stage. Any ideas what could be wrong? I have had no problems cloning or pulling code from the terminal onto this server. Server A (Jenkins) uses the following keys

Server A has the right keys to access the repository on Server B (its obvious as the pipeline runs, but stating it nevertheless)
Server A has the keys (PEM file) to login to server C and change to the working directory
Server C's public keys are available on Server B (Git) to allow passwordless PULL of the code into Server C

and they seem to be
